# DataGrid default column filter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

Lets say we have a DataGrid which populated with 2 columns: "First Name" and "Last Name".

My goal is to sort DataGrid  by LastName. It should be working when ObservableCollection (behind DataGrid) is appending or items being removed from it.

Is there some simple XAML solution or or just i have to do via the code ?

P.S.
I aware of ICollectionView solution, but i looking for small and natural fix.

Comment: You want it to always sort by Last Name?

Comment: Yep, this is the idea

Answer (score 0):

Use SortedList as your data context, and in your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged
this will replace the ObservableCollection.
and with SortedList you can sort your collection for your needs...

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` as suggested by user1763180 will only work if you call `OnPropertyChanged` every time you `Add` to the collection. `ObservableCollection` is convenient because you do not need to deal with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

The easiest way is to call

```
dataGridView.Sort(dataGridView.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

on your `DataGridView`.

Another option: either calling `Insert` or overriding the `Add` method to use `Insert` to automatically keep your collection sorted.

```
public void Add(string firstName, string lastName)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < _lastNames.Count; i++)
  {
    if (lastName.CompareTo(_lastNames.Items[i]) >= 0)
    {
      _lastNames.Insert(i, lastName);
      _firstNames.Insert(i, firstName);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would skip the DataGrid and use a read only GridView ListView

This code is just hand entered and not tested but but I do something close

```
private ObservableCollection<person> persons;

public ObservableCollection<person> PersonsSorted { get { return persons.orderby(x => x.LastName; } }
```

Bind the ListView to PersonsSorted
It will get add and delete

Use other controls to add and remove from persons.
If you edit will need to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged